# Multiple Substring is not working in MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In razor view below For Each using

```
 @foreach (var i in (List<MyDME.Data.Model.ERNFileRequestDTO>)ViewBag.lst)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo.Count; j++)
                        {

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Parse835Details.storedPayorName[j]
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo[j]
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Parse835Details.storedTotalBilled[j]

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Parse835Details.storedTotalPaid[j]

                                </td>
                                <td>
                              //below line doing substring which is not working
   @(i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(4, 5) + " " + i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(6, 7) + " " + i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(0, 3))
                                   
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href='/PatientManagement/DownloadUploadedDocument?fileName=@Html.Raw(i.path)'>Download</a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

below error is getting

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length'
```

IF i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j] vlaues is `20210225` like that date format is coming in string, from this value doing substring but not able to do substring for multiple substring.

if i use below single range then its working

```
@i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(0, 5)
```

if i use below single range then its not working

```
@i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(4, 5)
```

Comment: Can you show your storedChkNo and storedChkDate classes pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the method [`public string Substring (int startIndex, int length)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_).
But it seems you think it is *`public string Substring (int startIndex, int endIndex)`*.

The extract characters 4 + 5, you need to pass `length` as 2, as follows:

```
@i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(4, 2)
```

And similar for the other calls.

Comment: @(i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(4, 5) + " " + i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(6, 7) + " " + i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(0, 3))
   how to achieve above line. @Peter B

Comment: still i did not understood. @Peter B

Comment: I would say that I showed what you need to do with the first call, followed by "And similar for the other calls". What is unclear about that? Use `2` if you want to extract 2 characters, use `4` if you want to extract 4. See the link that I posted (first inline code block).

Comment: I agree with @Peter B, the explanation is very clear.  I would suggest that reading how Substring works would be helpful - this may help you? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/substring-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: You super hero for me, i am trying since 6 hours. @Peter B